# Discrete "Jumps" in Independent Variable

Tags: time-series, least-squares, econometrics

Suppose I have an independent variable which is available on a monthly basis as follows - the variable assumes a certain value for a given quarter, and then changes in the following quarter. Therefore, the chart of the variable resembles a step function of sorts, with discrete jumps.

Are there any potential problems with using OLS in such a case?

Comment: Using OLS for what purpose in what way??  Certainly OLS is not theoretically applicable if you attempt to fit this variable as a function of any explanatory variables, because the errors will be strongly interdependent.  All estimates of uncertainty and variability will be suspect.  Notwithstanding, you often can get great fits if your purpose is just to smooth the plot.

Comment: 1. I would suggest using at least an AR(1) error structure to account for potential error time-dependence. 2. Assuming we one measurement pcm, that is fine but if they are daily, (i.e. we indeed have step functions) then maybe another approach is better.

Comment: @whuber I made a mistake - I meant independent variable

Comment: I think your question might become much clearer if you were to explain just how you plan to employ this variable and what makes you think its discrete behavior might be problematic.

Comment: Looking to use a measure of the fiscal deficit (which is quarterly) in a monthly regression as a control variable. I could assume the quarterly values for each month, but that might lead to misleading jumps in the x-variables, and viewing the process as smoother (eg: linearly interpolated) may be more apt.